# Copying active sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder full of workbooks (VBA), and I am trying to copy ONLY the active sheets (all of the "first" sheets are active) to new workbooks. Is there anyway to copy the active sheet without specifying the sheet name? Not all of the "first" sheets in the folder have the same name, but all the ones I desire are active.

Comment: `Set wb=Workbooks.Open("path_here"): wb.Sheets(1).Copy...`

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
Sub whatAreTheyCalled()
Dim w As Workbook
Dim s As Worksheet

For Each w In Application.Workbooks
  Set s = w.ActiveSheet
  MsgBox "the active sheet is " & s.Name
Next w

End Sub
```

This shows how you find the name of the active sheet in each of the open workbooks. You should be able to take it from there.